# firebase onMessage not called when tab focused

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My goal is to implement push notifications in a pwa.
To get started with firebase I donwloaded the example for messaging.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/messaging/README.md

I send messages using postman like:

```
 {
    "notification": {
    "title": "Alarm",
    "body": "Temperature to high!",
    "icon": "https://www.somewebsite.com/someimage.jpg",
    "click_action": "http://localhost:8081"
  },
  "data":{
    "code": "a3545gae"
  },
  "to": "secrettokengBuX9NcFiIvmsM2lSoZlcnMWr5_Ldekta9Kl234vIqTzy7WXeioamyLdL7bYCnDCXBYJIsNrKZlUIct9VDLfjQrdmGZsefJF8KJdc_"
  }
```

I run my app with `firebase serve -p 8081` And I get the expected website running on port 8081.
The moment I send a post request to send a notification and I dont have a browser tab open with the page, the notification is shown as expected. 
[image]

When I do have a tab open with the page and I send a post request nothing happens, I was expexting onMessage to be called.

```
// [START receive_message]
  // Handle incoming messages. Called when:
  // - a message is received while the app has focus
  // - the user clicks on an app notification created by a service worker
  //   `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler` handler.
  messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Update the UI to include the received message.
    appendMessage(payload);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
  });
  // [END receive_message]
```

The full code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging).
I tested with chrome and edge.
However I do not see any popup or anything in the console. 
Do I need to do something else to get the data in the console?